# HTML5 + CSS Overlapping an image on top of Text/Padding

Tags: css, html, image, text, overlap

I am trying to overlap an image on the top of my text padding as you can see here:
I want to turn this where the image is currently at the back, to get on the top of the text

http://puu.sh/gz2AW/883a840919.png

With the image being on the top.
As you can see, the text padding overlaps the image behind it.

Here is a Jfiddle of the relevant code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ymc3bruz/2/

```
<div>  
    <img id="khufuimg" src="images/khufu.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:150px;height:150px">
    <p id="secondPageParagraph"> The Great pyramids of Giza are some of the most famous<br> man-made objects in the world. The Great Pyramid <br> of Khufu is the only
wonder of the ancient world that<br> still survives to this day.<br> <br>
    <br>It is 756 feet long on each side, 450 feet high and is <br>composed of 2.3 Million blocks of stones, each averaging<br> 2 1/2 tons in weight.  <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

---

```
#khufuimg{
position:absolute;
margin-left:600px;
margin-top:100px;  }


#secondPageParagraph{
position:absolute;
margin-left:160px;
margin-top:100px;
padding-right:189px;
font-family:courier new;
background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using display block and putting a higher z-index value?

Comment: also edit the jFiddle because the image can't be seen since the source is a local one, you need to upload it somewhere to allow people from internet to see it :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me, Im still learning this language.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ymc3bruz/1/

Comment: but in the fiddle the image isn't even in the viewport

Comment: Resize the fiddle so the scroll bar shows up and you'll be able to see it, its because of my margin settings on the image

Comment: you want it to work exactly as this image http://puu.sh/gz2AW/883a840919.png?

Comment: No, i want it to work like this image http://puu.sh/gz3F8/8f4e8cfb08.png

Comment: I want to help you, but in the fiddle the text doesn't even touch the image unless you make the viewport wider. In this case, the text overlaps the image so no problem

Comment: Ohh i got it, you want the image on top? WAIT A MINUTE

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ymc3bruz/3/

Comment: you're welcome, for you know, when the image is positioned you can adjust the layer order with `z-index`. The higher the value, the more on top the element will be.

Answer (score 0):

```
#khufuimg{
position:absolute;
margin-left:400px;
margin-top:0px;
z-index:10;
}
```

Where do you want the picture precise friend?